# Pixel art quartered palette

Tags: export, file-format, pixel-art, palette

This is a shoot in the blind, as it is a very old school project I work on. I’m an unprofessional in terms of art and programming, but got the source code (legally obtained) of the first ever 3D football game developed both for Mac and PC in the 90s. I work in Mac OS 9.2.

The team used a quartered palette , which in HEX only goes to 3F. I can upload the artwork and add the palette, but it doesn’t save it after a change to that same format. Are there any expertise around on how to load and afterwards save in this format? Might be doable in Adobe Illustrator for OS8-9 etc.